# JavaScript script working in HTML code tester but not on website

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

This is the code. It used to work before but it suddenly stopped working.

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin:0; border-top:1px ;     font-size: 16px;
border-top: 1px ;
background: #1367ad;
border-bottom: 1px ; padding: 15px;
color: #fff; -moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;"> Today: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.al-habib.info/ical-js/jsphp.php"></script></div>
```

The content inside the div are working but the content from the PHP file are not. So the result is only "Today:" and the date which is coming from the PHP file is not displayed.

Comment: You need to indicate in your question what isn't working.  Your question should contain everything needed to reproduce your problem.  Otherwise, you'll fix your site and your question won't be useful to others.

Comment: @Brad yes, we both agree that, that is what I meant

Comment: @Jac Ah, I see now.  Cheers!  :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Jsphp should be run in https url . Your website is running under https and the internal .jsphp file which you are using, that is under http. Please change that to https. So it will definitly work.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the URL to https and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you just open up the developer console, you have the problem stated clearly.

[image: Mixed Content: The page peacecentre.uk was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script. This request has been blocked.]

If you can edit the code, try just changing the link to use https.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to troubleshoot the problem, I tried multiple things but am no expert in HTML or PHP.